# Reuse code between two different .net applications

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, code-reuse

My asp.net (4.5 framework)project is a traditional webforms project. It is a small project. Here there is no separation of data/business layers. All classes are with App_Code. Now i want to use these same classes from a .net windows service.

If i add the single dll of the project, then i would be able to use the classes. But instead is there any other easy way to use only those classes without adding the dll of the project. (i.e) Is it possible to generate two different dlls, one of which to contain the app_code classes alone. So that i can copy this dll alone into my windows service.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create a [new class library project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3cye135(v=vs.110).aspx), then add references to that class library from your website and your Windows service projects. Move all shared functionality from the App_Code folder into the class library. Depending on how well you separated your concerns, you may need to remove some web specific stuff.

Alternatively, you may create a class library project in a new solution, then use [NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/) to distribute it. But that's probably overkill for getting started.

Comment: thanks. good answer. i will try this out.

one more small advice needed. i also have to reuse the appsettings defined in the web.config of the web project. Is is a good solution to download this xml file using some handler e.t.c.. and use it in my webservice start method?

Comment: No, because web.config files can contain sensitive information. Instead, copy/paste the needed values into the app.config or create an API on your web service that the service can call in order to obtain settings information.

Comment: ok. Can i add api inside web application(not webservice). can you post a link for that?

Comment: Sure can. It's called [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). Although you might also consider [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx). Web API is simpler, WCF is more flexible.